# learning bash: Can't activate environment

Tags: bash

I've set up Ubuntu in Windows 10 and am in my home directory:

```
/mnt/c/Users/Me$
```

I want to end up in my environment directory and have it activated.

I created a file called goenv.sh in this directory and it contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
source environments/my_env/bin/activate
```

I changed the permissions of goenv.sh then tried to run it with:

```
./goenv.sh
```

...but nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: Trying sourcing `goenv.sh`, e.g. `. ./goenv.sh`?

Comment: That activates the environment but it doesn't go into the `environments` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script `./goenv.sh` runs in a sub shell. That means that all environment changes are local to that sub shell but have no impact on the calling shell (the shell where you started it).

You need to define a function in your `.bashrc` to achieve that:

```
function goenv() {
    cd environments
    source my_env/bin/activate
}
```

Anyhow, that looks like a Python virtualenv. I recommend to install `virtualenvwrapper` which comes with handy shell functions to work with virtualenvs. Having it installed, you just run:

```
workon my_env
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now. I changed the script shown in my question to:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd environments
source ./my_env/bin/activate
```